# How to reset sql identity value per year?

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

Hi' I'm working with an asp.net application wich related to the registration of students, the data related to the students is inserted in to a database, each time a student is registered the field idStudent is incremented by one, what I want to do is when a new year begins reset the student value in order to begin from 1 in the new year.

- idStudent    Year  1            2011 2            2011 3
  2011 4            2011 5            2011 ..... 1            2012 2
  2012 3            2012 .......

How can I do this?
The databse is in sql server 2008

Hope your help

Comment: There is no good way of doing this. Best to drop the requirement if it is not entirely non-negotiable.

Comment: You're probably way better off just creating the composite key of (StudentID, Year)

Comment: Do you need to keep other students (from previous years) in the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had this exact business requirement and I couldn't negotiate a better, more efficient way then this would be my approach:

Instead of using an artificial key (i.e. an `identity` column) I would utilize a composite key.  To find out what your best bet for a composite key would be, you need to know the business rules and logic.  In other words, a question you would have to ask is *is the combination of year and id unique?  In other words, per year a student id can only be used once...?*

This is one of those times were you would benefit from a natural composite key.

Comment: I use the field IdStudent to know how many students are registered per year that's why I need to "reset" IdStudent per year

Comment: Create a primary key on `(Year, StudentId)`.  As for the `StudentId` field, don't have it as an `identity` field.  Just use some database/application logic to increment by one when a user is inserted, and if it's a new year then start back at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a computed column which derives the number based on the year. You just need to run the script below at the start of the new year. Do note that when a transaction is rolled back there will be gaps in the identity column. (and inserts in a previous year will create big gaps as well.)

```
-- test table & inserts
create table Students (Id int identity, year int, name varchar(20), StudentId int null)
insert into Students (year, name) values (2010, 'student1'), (2011, 'student1'), (2011, 'student2')

-- run this every year
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE Students DROP COLUMN StudentId ')
declare @count int, @sql varchar(max), @year int

declare c cursor local read_only 
for select year + 1, max(Id) from Students group by year

open c

fetch next from c into @year, @count
select @sql = 'when year = ' + convert(varchar(10), @year - 1) + ' then Id '+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  begin
    select @sql = @sql + 'when year = ' + convert(varchar(10), @year) + ' then Id - ' + convert(varchar(10), @count) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    fetch next from c into @year, @count
  end
close c
deallocate c
select @sql = 'CASE ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @sql + ' ELSE 0 END'
select @sql = 'ALTER TABLE Students ADD StudentId AS ' + isnull(@sql, 'Id') + '  PERSISTED'

exec (@sql)
```